# USB Send Simple Output or Allow Current Flow?

Tags: transistors, usb

I need to write a program that will turn on an external power supply by allowing current to flow through. This should be controlled via USB and should let current flow between the PSU pins. I know I could do this with an Arduino, but I'm looking for a simpler and cheaper solution. Is there a cheap USB device for allowing current flow (or outputting power to a transistor that will allow the current flow) that I can program to send an output?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to control your output from a PC application? If you need only a single pin, and your application can access a serial port I suggest using an USB-to-serial converter, either an RS232 version (very common), or one with a TTL-level output. Use a handshake output pin, for instance RTS. In most serial port libraries you can set this pin directly.

Comment: If I were to choose this option, what would I connect to what?

Comment: You said you know how to do this with an Arduino. An USB-to-serial converter provides a few pins that you can control from your PC. The RTS pin is probably the easiest one. You can easily find which one it is by googling. If this is gibberish to you I suggest you take a ready made solution like Andy Aka suggests.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/acatalog/Relay_Modules.html) site seems to have a few USB relay controllers. Here's one that maybe you can use: -

[image]

If it is too expensive there are probably cheaper options elsewhere. The relay contacts are rated to switch up to 250Vac at 16A which should be enough for most people's needs.

[Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/usb-relay-controller) has one that looks similar for $13 and there's a single relay option at about $11 further down the page.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, an USB relay is probably more direct approach. You will find a lot of them on the internet, for instance:

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-actuators/yocto-powerrelay
http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=9

However, before choosing the cheapest one, make sure it comes with a decent API.

Btw, your power supply is probably a big inductive load. Make sure you protect your brand new relay with the proper TVS diode, more explanation here:

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/relay-and-inductive-loads